# Should we ban smileys?

Tags: discussion

I just saw a question on SO that used 5 smileys in the title, the body, and if it had been possible the tag. My eyes feel so very sore right now.

What's the benefit in a title and/or question?

Am I being grumpy?

Here is the Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358180/how-to-make-jar-from-zip-in-android-studio-and-eclipse

I just realized it does not render the same way on mobile and desktop. Desktop is much less aggressive.

Comment: I think they should do it to some extent. Currently, you must have at least 10 reputation to embed images in your post, and I think that should also apply to smilies.

Comment: Smileys are useful on some diskusion forums, but here they seam to be wrong.

Comment:  Cat smiley says no 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Smileys are almost always a form of chit chat that on Main sites should only be available and/or remain in comments.

Our [tours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) are explicit about there being no chit chat.

I would not expect to see a [Smiley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smiley) on a Wikipedia page, except when a page is about displaying, rendering or otherwise interacting with that Smiley, and we create wiki-style Q&As rather than holding conversations, so I think similar conventions should apply to our sites.

Perhaps we can be less strict on Meta sites but I think that would spill over into the Main sites.

Answer (score 7):

Ban outright? Nah. But if you see something that makes the question, say, hard to read, feel free to edit it to make it better.

For me, overused smilies would fall in the "this needs an edit" category. I use them on occasion otherwise, though, so wouldn't advocate a strict ban. :)

Comment: Well a text smiley is much less aggressive than an emoticon... I think the latter is what ticked me because it is so distracting

Comment: @DavidBrossard Ahh, I didn't know what question you were referring to, so I assumed text smileys. Although, I'd probably treat emoji about the same - one is probably okay, excessive use should be edited.

Comment: It was this one. On PC it renders better. On mobile it's a emoji fireworks... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358180/how-to-make-jar-from-zip-in-android-studio-and-eclipse

Comment: @DavidBrossard Fair. That didn't look *too* horrible to me personally, but even so there were some grammar problems with the question as well, so I edited it all into shape.

Comment: 

Comment: The only palce where smileys make sence is chat.

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion, this should be implemented to some extent. Currently, you must have at least 10 reputation to embed images in your post, and I think that should also apply to smileys.

If such a filter is implemented, rather than simply responding to attempts to include smileys with an automated message saying "smileys are not allowed", I imagine that it would be more helpful to display a reminder that Stack Exchange prefers that posts are "straight to the point" and "without fluff."

This would feel less hostile than a blanket, unexplained ban on such content.